# Function to initiate translation or rotation

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm wondering if I'm doing this correctly.

I have an enemy moving around my level doing different things at different locations. For instance, move to a point, then turn to face the player. Shoot a few times, then move to the next point. All the moving I am doing via script - `transform.translate`, `transform.rotate` etc, and triggering the armature animations programmatically.

I have it set up so that when an enemy reaches a point I flick a boolean over, and then I have a bunch of `if`s in the `Update` which check which boolean is currently true, and applies the root motion accordingly. Observe:

```
void Update () {
    if (!atNode) {
        transform.LookAt (selectedNode.transform);
        transform.Translate (Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed);
    }


    if (Vector3.Distance (transform.position, selectedNode.position) < 5) {
        atNode = true;
    }
}
```

This seems like a really silly way to do all this. I'd much prefer to just have a `moveToPoint( vec3 )` function which I could fire off at will, and have the enemy move to that point outside the `Update()` but the only logic I can think for that function is essentially a wrapper for what I am already doing.

How is root motion usually handled in this environment?

Comment: Hello, I would suggest you to use `FixedUpdate()` for that kind of operation. Also look for `Rigidbody` instead of simple `trasform`.

Comment: @Morasiu please elaborate. You should use FixedUpdate when moving physics based objects on your scene, since FixedUpdate is called before the physics logic is run. Using Update runs the risk of weird physics bugs. By all means have a MoveTo(Vec3) function that sets a target variable, and in the FixedUpdate move towards that target until you're there, but I would strongly advise against breaking away from FixedUpdate to move your characters. Don't over-complicate things. If you're component is becoming too complex, split the component into multiple components.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you want a "smooth" movement, which I suppouse that you want it, you don't want that the enemy randomly teleports, implies a Coroutine, or at least one thread that handles it (as far as I know).

But avoiding that point, you can use **"MoveTowards()"** : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html

To accomplish the "moveToPoint(vec3)" that you want.

Answer (score 0):

yes use fixed update as The Fish says. and `MoveTowards` as Lotan suggested... but i wanted to point out a couple more methods...

theres:

```
transform.LookAt(target);
```

(which your using)

this will take the transform of the gameObject and rotate it to look at target(which is also a transform, presumably your player obj)

but i think you want

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.RotateTowards.html

it takes a vector three, but you can rotate it on only one axis... you will use it just like your rotate function above, with deltatime and speed, but you should get a lot smoother rotation over time, without any jumping or snapping.